# Jquery dynamically created draggable divs

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-draggable, dynamically-generated

In my project im creating dynamically divs with jquery everytime you click a button. Now i want these new divs to have draggable and resizable properties. Here is what ive done so far:

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
     $("<div/>", {
       "id": "test",
        text: "",
      }).appendTo("body");
     $( "#test" ).resizable();
     $( "#test" ).draggable();
  });
```

This code works somehow, the problem is that only the first div that was created is resizable and draggable. 
Also is it possible to put another button in order to delete these new created divs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`id` must be unique! you create multiple divs with the same `test` id => **INVALID HTML**

Another thing, you don't need to query the DOM, you can use the reference you got to make the created `<div>` `resizable` and `draggable`:

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
     $("<div/>", {
       "class": "test",
        text: "",
      }).resizable().draggable()
      .appendTo("body");
  });
```

If you want to use id for some reason:

```
var counter = 1;

$("#button1").click(function(){
     $("<div/>", {
       "class": "test" + (counter++),
        text: "",
      }).resizable().draggable()
      .appendTo("body");
  });
```

`#id` selector comment in the [docs site](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

> Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one element using the same ID is invalid.

Comment: Thanx for the answers! So how i can create different id's for each div with one button?

Comment: @lucky13. You can use a variable to store the counter **see the update**. or just use class instead.

Comment: thank you very much!everything's working now! The other question now.. is it possible to add another button in order to delete all the created divs?

Comment: @lucky13. You should ask one question in a tread, ask it in other question and me or someone else would be happy to help you with it.

Answer (score 1):

You should give different id for each and every click or else use class with similar name..

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
     $("<div/>", {
       "class": "test",
        text: "",
      }).appendTo("body");
     $( ".test" ).resizable();
     $( ".test" ).draggable();
  });
```